# Examples of real-valued functions $f,g$ such that $L(f+g, [0,1])\neq L(f, [0,1])+L(g, [0,1])$ and $U(f+g, [0,1])\neq U(f, [0,1])+L(g, [0,1])$?

Tags: real-analysis

As per the title, I need to come up with real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ such that $$L(f+g, [0,1])\neq L(f, [0,1])+L(g, [0,1])$$ and $$U(f+g, [0,1])\neq U(f, [0,1])+L(g, [0,1]).$$  So in other words, I need to find $f$ and $g$ such that

$$\underline\int_{0}^1 (f+g)\neq \underline\int_{0}^1 f+\underline\int_{0}^1 g$$ and $$\overline\int_{0}^1 (f+g)\neq \overline\int_{0}^1 f+\overline\int_{0}^1 g.$$  I feel like the only functions $f$ and $g$ that would work here are ones that are not Riemann integrable.  I know that a classic example of a non-Riemann integrable function is the Dirichlet function, i.e. $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \text{ is rational} \\
0 & x\text{ is irrational}\end{cases}\\$$ which has $L(f,[0,1])=0$ and $U(f,[0,1])=1$.  But (assuming I am on the right track here) I still need another function $g$ and somehow have to consider $f+g$.

Any suggestions with this one?

Comment: Easy. Let $g = -f$.

Comment: So would something like $f=\cos(x), g=-\cos(x)$ work?

Comment: Or are you referring to $f$ as being the Dirichlet function defined in the post?

Comment: Seems no, $f,g $ are Riemann integrable.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, $f$ is the Dirichlet function. Sorry I was ambiguous.

Comment: @xbh you should post this as an answer(and not a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f = \mathbb 1_{\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]}$, $g = -f$, then $f+g =0$ is always Riemann integrable, hence $L(f+g) = U(f+g) = 0$. But $U(f) = 1, L(f) = U(g) = 0, L(g)=-1$.

Comment: Thanks for making this into an answer.  What does $1_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}$ mean?

Comment: That's a standard notation of Dirichlet function. You could see [indicator function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) in wiki.

Comment: I was unaware of that.  Thank you.